# A lot of syntax errors

Tags: java, android

I am very new to Android and Java programming and I am getting errors but I don't understand what is wrong here.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_world);

    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(HelloWorld.this, HelloWorld.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    )
}}
```

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: @Boss OP already provided shortest possible program necessary to reproduce problem. While his issues can look like typographical errors to the experienced developers, it is quite clear that in this case it is not typo error, but fact that OP does not know how to properly create and assign `OnClickListener`. This is valid question, no matter how simple it may look.

Comment: Thank you alot @DalijaPrasnikar

Comment: When you encounter compiler errors, you should always focus in solving them one by one in order they appear, because once compiler chokes on invalid code it is very likely that subsequent code will not be correctly interpreted and some of errors can be bogus.

Comment: Thanks for your help @DalijaPrasnikar

Comment: You are welcome. BTW, event though I think this is valid question, it is not exactly stellar one. In future you can avoid asking such questions by doing better research of what you are trying to do. For instance, in this case you had syntax errors in `setOnClickListener` code. Googling for `setOnClickListener example` would give you plenty of examples to choose from. Comparing them to your code would reveal your errors.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to close the onClick method, and you are missing a semi-colon at the end of the `btn.setOnClickListener(...)` statement. And your `OnClickListener` anonymous class instance is missing enclosing curly braces.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_world);

    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick() {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(HelloWorld.this, HelloWorld.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating an anonymous class which is not following syntax.The method parameter containing the instance of anonymous class should have the definition and declaration something like this :-

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_world);

    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(HelloWorld.this, HelloWorld.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }});
}
```